# on click toggle for child element of the certain class (handlers) - jquery

Tags: handler, parent-child, jquery

When I click on parent, I need to affect one particular child (toggle it's style).

I achieved toggle functionality with handlers:

```
$(".p1").on({
    mouseenter: mouseEnter,
    mouseleave: mouseLeave
});
function mouseEnter() {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 5px #999999');
}
function mouseLeave() {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid transparent 5px');
}
function handler1() {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid 5px #222222');
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $(this).one("click", handler2);
}
function handler2() {
    $(this).css('border', 'solid transparent 5px');
    $(this).on({mouseenter: mouseEnter, mouseleave: mouseLeave});
    $(this).one("click", handler1);
}
$(".p1a").parent(".p1").one("click", handler1);
$(".pl").children(".p1").one("click", handler1); //this one doesn't work
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2czxN/4/

Everything works except for affecting the child by clicking on it's parent (aka the last line).

How can this functionality be added to this function?

Comment: What's the different between `$(".p1a").parent(".p1").` and `$(".pl").children(".p1")` - at the minute they are both targeting the same element.

Comment: yes they are. I don't know how to click on parent without affecting it - I only need to affect the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final function - [**http://jsfiddle.net/2czxN/6/**](http://jsfiddle.net/2czxN/6/)

Works 100% accurately regardless if you click on children (p1a) or parent (pl).

```
$(".p1a").one("click", handler1);
$(".pl").one("click", handler1);
```

Key is in putting all selectors (`find`, `parent`) in the handlers with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

The only diffrence in your fiddle is, that the .pl wraps just the first .p1, so the second wont work...

```
$(".pl").children(".p1").one("click", handler1); //this one doesn't work

<div class="pl" style="width: 300px; height: 150px; background: #888888; border: solid white 5px;">
    <div class="p1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #555555; border: solid transparent 5px;">
        <div class="p1a" style="width: 200px; height: 10px; background: #333333;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="p1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #555555; border: solid transparent 5px;">
        <div class="p1a" style="width: 200px; height: 10px; background: #333333;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

yes, i just wanted to explain why the second declaration isnt working on the seconed p1..
im not sure what you want to achive, something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/reyaner/3yZmW/

Comment: neither one work. also, there is a reason why I've made that div structure - changing it doesn't really answer this question.

Comment: not at all but you've shown me the light by putting `find` in the handlers. thanks for the help